# element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(innNa)) will not overwrite with new data

Tags: javascript, html, function, random, appendchild

I am working on TTRPG assets to use in my own games. The intended functionality is to take form selections that will be fed into several randomized tables and produce relevant outputs.

> Inn generator form: https://output.jsbin.com/pilobob/1/quiet

Currently the **Generate Output** button correctly appends relevant output below the form when ran on a fresh page, however, further **Generate Output** events do not overwrite the old data.

```
            <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="randGen(selection.value);" name="GenerateOutput" value="Generate Output"> 
        </form>
        <div class="genSection" id="genSection">
            <div id="randQua">
                <div id="selection">
            </div>
            <div id="randNam">
                <div id="selection">
            </div>
```

```
function randGen(){
    randQua();
    randNam();
}

function randNam(selection){
    var selection = document.getElementById('quality');
    let br="";
    let element=document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id","selection");
    for(i=0;
    i<1;
    i++){if(selection.value==1){rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*innNa1.length);
    innNa=innNa1[rnd];
    }else{rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*innNa2.length);
        innNa=innNa2[rnd];
        }
    br=document.createElement('br');
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(innNa));
    element.appendChild(br);
    }
    if(document.getElementById("selection")){document.getElementById("randNam").removeChild(document.getElementById("selection"));
    }
    document.getElementById("randNam").appendChild(element);
    }
    
    
function randQua(selection){
    var selection = document.getElementById('quality');
    let br="";
    let element=document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id","selection");
    for(i=0;
    i<1;
    i++){if(selection.value==1){rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*innQu1.length);
    innQu=innQu1[rnd];
    }else{rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*innQu2.length);
        innQu=innQu2[rnd];
        }
    br=document.createElement('br');
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(innQu));
    element.appendChild(br);
    }
    if(document.getElementById("selection")){document.getElementById("randQua").removeChild(document.getElementById("selection"));
    }
    document.getElementById("randQua").appendChild(element);
    }
```

I need the button to recalculate and append the randGen function (and all contained *rnd* variables) on click.

> JS bin: https://jsbin.com/pilobob/1/edit?html,js

*It's not central to my concerns, however if there is a way to make the appended values append in chronological order instead of inverse chronological order, I would like to be made aware.*

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `appendChild`, with it you can add content to elements without overriding the old content.

Comment: You're *appending* data to the element. If you want to replace the current data in the element, you should do `element.innerHTML = innNa;`.

Comment: *"...if there is a way to make the appended values append in chronological order instead of inverse chronological order, I would like to be made aware."* `.appendChild()` and `.append()` are FILO (**F**irst **I**n **L**ast **O**ut). **`.prepend()`** is FIFO.